# QML Video native size

Tags: qt, video, qml

I am playing a video with QML like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0 


Video
{
  source:'movie.mov'
  width: 800
  height: 600
  autoPlay:true
}
```

which works, but I would like the movie to be displayed in its original resolution. So whatever movie file I load, I expect the Video element to scale to the video resolution. However,

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0 


Video
{
  source:'movie.mov'
  autoPlay:true
}
```

will play the video (i can hear sound) but not display anything.

Any suggestions ? (Qt 5.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind width and height to the [video resolution](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qtmobility/qml-video.html#metaData.resolution-prop) like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0 


Video
{
  source:'movie.mov'
  width: metaData.resolution ? metaData.resolution.width : 0
  height: metaData.resolution ? metaData.resolution.height : 0
  autoPlay:true
}
```

Comment: While this seems to work i get these error messages: <Unknown File>: TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined
<Unknown File>: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Comment: I edited my code above to avoid undefined references when the video isn't loaded yet (`metaData.resolution` is undefined until then)